# RegEx - Insert hyphen between words in URL

Tags: regex, google-sheets-api

Not sure the possibility of this given that there isn't really a specific letter to identify, but I'm needing to use RegEx to insert hyphens between words in a URL. The code will need to be applicable to hundreds of different urls within the same sitemap.

I'm also doing this in Google Sheets, so I'm using the RegExreplace function:

I've already got it working for URL strings that have capital letters:

```
String: NewYorkCityOffices
Function:  =regexreplace(A1,"([a-z])([A-Z])","$1-$2")
Output: New-York-City-Offices
```

But now I'm needing to do the same for strings that are entirely lowercase, see example:

```
String: mysearchpageresults
Desired Output: my-search-page-results
```

Like I said, this will need to be applicable to hundreds of different strings containing different words.

Is it even possible to achieve this without a common identifier (like how we used a capital letter as the identifier in the first example)?

Comment: Looks like you need some NLP word tokenizer for English.

Comment: This isn't possible without a dictionary of acceptable words, and even then you may have multiple solutions. Consider `expertsexchange` - hyphenate before the `s`, or after?

Comment: @nrabinowitz before the `s` for sure.

Comment: I figured this wouldn't be possible without some sort of NLP. Thanks for taking a look.